# Cucumber rails test result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I am learning cucumber / capybara on rails. I working on a scenario that expects to display sorted data from a table. I cannot figure out this message:

pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had

I have this table:

```
  | title                   | rating | release_date |
  | Aladdin                 | G      | 25-Nov-1992  |
  | The Terminator          | R      | 26-Oct-1984  |
  | When Harry Met Sally    | R      | 21-Jul-1989  |
  | The Help                | PG-13  | 10-Aug-2011  |
  | Chocolat                | PG-13  | 5-Jan-2001   |
  | Amelie                  | R      | 25-Apr-2001  |
  | 2001: A Space Odyssey   | G      | 6-Apr-1968   |
  | The Incredibles         | PG     | 5-Nov-2004   |
  | Raiders of the Lost Ark | PG     | 12-Jun-1981  |
  | Chicken Run             | G      | 21-Jun-2000  |
```

Below is my step definition:

```
When(/^I clicked "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1|
  if arg1 == "Movie Title"
   click_link ("title_header")
  end
end

Then(/^I expect "(.*)" before "(.*)"$/) do |arg1, arg2|
 assert page.body.expect =~ /arg1.*arg2/
end
```

The message again I am trying to resolve is below:

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

```
Then(/^I expect to see "(.*?)" before "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1, arg2|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the step correctly, you are missing the 'to see' in your step definition

Comment: Apparently I was not paying attention to that. Thanks Tom.